# How to $_GET array element from URL

Tags: php, html

I have this url:

> search.htm?postSearchForm=1&mediaTypes[3]=3

I need to get `mediaTypes[3]` with $_GET method

This code doesn't work:

```
$value = $_GET[mediaTypes[3]];
```

Comment: Do: `print_r($_GET);` and you will see the structure of your array. And I'm sure you will see the solution right away :)

Comment: $value = $_GET[mediaTypes][3];

Comment: print $_GET and fetch your value from whatever index

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
 $value = $_GET['mediaTypes'][3];
```

And don't forget to filter the data, for example

```
 if (ctype_digit($_GET['mediaTypes'][3])) 
    $value = $_GET['mediaTypes'][3];
```